# Minimum available passport blank page requirements

Tags: visas, passports, planning, regulations, uk-citizens

For a British Citizen travelling on business to one country for up to 30 days what are the maximum numbers of consecutive and not-necessarily-consecutive minimum blank pages required in a passport when applying for a single-entry visa <strike>and which country (or countries) imposes them</strike>?

An answer which is just two numbers (presumably each a single digit) would be adequate.

---

Small (eg Maldives) island nations may be ignored.
Where custom and practice departs from regulations (eg SA) it is the former that is more my interest.
I see a Canadian heard mention of a need for six blank pages.
Three for each seems more plausible, but I have not found which countries stipulate that, if any.
I recognise that what is correct today may be out-of-date tomorrow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47394/discussion-on-question-by-pnuts-minimum-available-passport-blank-page-requiremen).

Answer (score 7):

[Passportinfoguide](http://passportinfoguide.com/adding-passport-pages/) has a surprisingly vague answer, but it does appear that it's about as specific as you might get, as many countries' embassies don't provide this information.  From the page:

> There is no short answer that applies to every traveler. The
>   requirement varies from country to country. If you have (4) blank
>   pages then you are probably fine. If you have less than that it may be
>   an issue. It depends on the country you are visiting that will
>   determine how many blank pages you actually need. Most countries will
>   require that your passport have two (2) blank pages. Some countries
>   require up to four (4) blank visa pages. Some airlines will not allow
>   you to board the plane if this requirement in not met. If you are on a
>   connecting flight to a departure city check with the airlines because
>   sometimes they will not even let you board the flight to your
>   departure city if you passport doesn't have enough blank pages.

Another resource you can use to calculate requirements, if you're visiting several countries, is the [Gallery of passport stamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_passport_stamps_by_country_or_territory).  This at least shows you which countries use a small stamp, versus an entire page.

If I find out more info I'll add it in here, but at present this seems about as accurate as one might get.

Comment: Note that the gallery isn't just visas - it's entry and exit too.  So one country can quite easily spread across several pages.  But with nine pages for one country, you should be totally fine.  Don't forget about transit countries too though, if you're using any.

Comment: @pnuts heh, NZ passports only last 5 years. Annoying, but less of a running-out-of-blank-pages problem if you have to keep getting new ones.

Comment: Cheapest adult NZ one is [NZ$140](http://www.passports.govt.nz/Fees-and-charges---adult-passports) or about 70 quid, so sadly, yes :/