# If my Schengen visa starts on the day of arrival which is one day after embarking, would they let me get into the plane?

Tags: visas, schengen, airlines

I have a question, I applied for the Schengen visa through Germany, on the form they ask me when I'd arriving (to Germany) and when I'd returning. they take this exact date as the visa period.

I wondering if they would let me get into the plane, even though my flight it a day before the arrival.

Let get the real deal; let say this:

My visa is valid from 02/12/2014 to 02/02/2015. But, my flight is scheduled to be departing on 01/12/2014, but entering Germany 02/12/2014. the flight duration is almost 9hours and there is 7hours difference between Germany and the departing flight country.

Comment: No brainer, yes you will be allowed. The visa meant for you to enter Germany, not to enter the plane.. airline staff will get this I am sure they faced this zillion times before.

Comment: Thanks @MeNoTalk for you answer, so, what about the airport staff. I do not want to buy that expensive ticket and miss the flight. One have to pass through a lot of checking (at the airport) before get into the airline staff checking.

Comment: You can always call the airline and make sure to have the peace in mind..

Comment: In general the airline staff will be satisified if they are convinced you will be allowed into the country at the end of the flight. There is no other purpose to the airline visa check.

Comment: @JonathanReez In my experience "ahead of" typically means "before," so the title as you edited it was confusing.  I have changed it.

Answer (score 16):

The purpose of the airline checking your  ticket, visa and passport is to ensure that they can legally transport you to your destination, and believe from that evidence that you will be permitted into the country of destination.

For this to occur, you need to usually show some or all of:

- a return ticket, or exit ticket out of the destination country
- a valid passport, sometimes with [pages/months free on the passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37127/101)
- a visa for the country, valid for when you enter the country

So, for this question, the focus is on the visa. Their simple process will be - when he arrives, will he have a valid visa? Yes. Great, approved.

Similarly, if your visa was valid on the day you left and NOT when you arrived (ie you were arriving at the end of your visa for some weird reason) they'd hopefully not let you board, as when you arrive, your visa wouldn't be valid.

Conclusion: Fly, and enjoy Germany!