# Schengen visa validity start date

Tags: visas, schengen

My Chinese in-laws intend to visit us in one month from now. Their visa is valid from Nov 23rd.
Would it be possible for them to take the airplane on November 22nd in China and arrive in Schengen area on November 23rd?

Or does the visa already have to be valid upon departure?

In our particular case, they still need to transfer in Beijing first. The actual flight to Schengen zone effectively only departs on the 23rd so I guess that should be completely fine then?

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37336/my-visa-period-start-on-arrival-would-they-let-me-get-into-the-plane

Comment: As long as they arrive in the zone after midnight on 22 Nov (i.e., any time on 23 Nov), it's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The visa only has to be valid when you arrive in the Schengen zone, like any visa.

This is a very common question, and indeed others on other forums have even [emailed embassies to confirm](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g1137930-i13438-k5878557-Traveling_day_before_validity_of_Schengen_Visa-Schengen.html) and they've acknowledged it's fine.

If you really want to be certain the airline is ok with it, you could call or email them to put your mind at rest.