# Can I wait airside ~2.5h after arrival to meet a travel companion from another destination?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, singapore, sin

I am flying from Düsseldorf to Singapore where I am meeting my traveling companion coming from Christchurch, arriving about 2 1/2 hours after me.

My Question: Can I wait airside for my girlfriend to arrive and meet her before immigrating? Will this cause additional issues at immigration and customs? I will only have carry-on luggage.

Comment: This answers to this question will be insightful https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94124/can-i-board-if-my-flight-arrives-1-5-hours-before-my-uk-visa-becomes-valid

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed the question before asking. I also asked my father, an airline pilot, and some of his colleagues (gate agents, etc..) but the common answer was that it highly depends on the airport in question.

Comment: I doubt you will receive anything more definitive here. It is largely an opinion based question with your result based on many random variables. I would take a pilot and airline agents opinion over what you will get here, but sure no harm asking.

Comment: I've done it before at other airports, and I'd consider doing it there too, it's Singapore.  I mean if they do raise an eyebrow and ask what took so long, you could just tell the truth. It's not like there are signs saying "you must exit in 45 min" - you could have gone to the bathroom or had a shower even before exiting. I would have raised luggage as the only potential issue ,but you've said carry-on.  The passport control folk don't know what time your flight arrived, after all.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie Singapore airport has massive facilities before passport control, quite unlike Gatwick

Comment: SIN has a mixed arrivals/departures area. Who would even notice?

Comment: @Calchas the immigration officer might notice if the traveler's flight information comes up (perhaps from the computer after scanning the passport).

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, there is no global Answer to this question because, as noted, it depends greatly on the local circumstances.  However, Singapore is somewhat special in that there are no domestic flights so the entire terminal is on the other side of Immigration and 'Security' is essentially at the gate.  So, 'airside' is conceptually different there as opposed to say London or Hong Kong.

When arriving, you will be directed away from the Gate's Departure Lounge and into the main Terminal which is essentially all a Transit area.  You can wait for her there.

When the GF arrives, you won't be able to get right up to the gate, but close enough depending on the configuration.

There's more information in the edit history, I just don't remember enough right now and won't be able to refresh for ~4 months.

Comment: Actually, there are no domestic flights in Hong Kong. All flights are international.

Comment: @K.T.L.Lo Yes, but at HKG all arrivals are directed toward either Immigration or Transit where you re-clear 'security'.  In this respect, 'airside' at HKG is the same as most other transit airport such as LHR.  Loitering in pre-Immigration/Transit area will likely get noticed.