# What documents are required when travelling to the US under a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I received a B1/B2 visa to US (in a country different from my nationality)
Is the visa all I need, or do I need to show any other documents at the departing airport and/or the entry airport at the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airlines / immigration will check a few things:

- your passport should have several spare pages, and at least 6 months' validity into the future (although that probably got checked when you got your visa, make sure it's still accurate)
- you should have a return ticket, or evidence of a planned departure from the US (eg bus ticket out, or onward flight)
- evidence of where you'll be staying (itinerary, accommodation bookings, if any)
- funds for travel - not always asked for, but sometimes they'll want to know how you'll support yourself, especially if you're there for more than a few days.

Given you received it from a country other than your nationality(?), it's best to bring any visas for that other country you hold, if they're in a previous passport or similar (it happens sometimes).

Pretty much any question you had to answer [as evidence to get the visa](http://www.usavisitorvisa.com/visitorvisa/visitorvisa.htm#required) may come up again, so be prepared to provide evidence for those once more, as well as the above-mentioned items.

Comment: Is there a reasoning for "several pages?" I am not questioning the fact, just trying to figure out the reason, all they need is a place for one stamp or at best one blank page isnt it, or should I post that as a separate question :)

Comment: @skv it was an over-simplification, basically many countries including the US require more pages than you'd expect.  [We have a question on this topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37127/101) ... oh and [this one too](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/27225/101)

Comment: at what point can I expect these questions? At the airport of departure, or on arrival at the US immigration? Do I need to keep my documents such as police record, employment contract (which I had shown during visa interview), invitation from the US, etc, on me at all times?

Comment: @user13267 Mainly you'll want proof of funds (e.g. credit card or bank statements) and an onward/return ticket. You also need the street address of where you will stay the first night; this goes on the form you fill out while on the plane to the US. After you clear immigration, the passport is all you will really need to hold on to.